# Comparing an array to text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

How could one go about checking all the document's elements' `data` attributes, and if the contents of an attribute match a value from in an array, do something?

I have an array that I'm creating by grabbing the `name` and `value` attributes from text inputs. I want to, for example, compare the `value` of name "X" to the value of a `span` with a data-attribute of "X".

The code I currently have is this:

```
bulletinPreview.prototype.updatePreview = function () {
    var dataValues = new Array();

    $(".edit-bulletin input[type=text]").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            dataName = $this.attr("name"),
            dataValue = $this.attr("value");

        dataValues.push({
            "name": dataName, 
            "value": dataValue 
        });
    });

    $(".bulletin-preview .editable").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($.inArray($this.data("title"), dataValues.name !== -1)) {
            $this.text(dataValues[1].value);
        }
    });
};
```

It replaces the text for ALL elements with a `data-title` of `title` the second `value` (because I'm explicitly saying `dataValues[1]` just to see something work). How do I take this and make it modular, so that it just runs through all the elements, runs through the array, and if two values match, do something?

Comment: Your first step will be putting the `)` in the right place in `if ($.inArray($this.data("title"), dataValues.name !== -1))` (the first one should be after `dataValues.name`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var $preview = $(".bulletin-preview");
$.each(dataValues, function(index, entry) {
    var $edit = $preview.find('.editable[data-title="' + entry.name + '"]');
    $edit.text(entry.value); // No-op if no match
});
```

That assumes none of the names contains double quotes.

If the repeated searches through `$preview` bother you, you can do one search and make yourself a map:

```
var map = {};
$(".bulletin-preview .editable").each(function() {
    map[this.getAttribute("data-title")] = this;
});
$.each(dataValues, function(index, entry) {
    var edit = map[entry.name];
    if (edit) {
        $(edit).text(entry.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Haven't done much work with maps before, but this is great to pick apart now and see how they work. Thanks!